# How can I find all archived posts in a Buy and Sell?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-archive

I'm an admin of a Facebook group that sells antiques. After 90 days, Facebook archives these posts. I'm okay with this, but most of the time I'd like to repost the item if it hasn't sold. But I can't find this set of archived posts. Is there a special search I can use, like Gmail's `has:attachment` or `in:inbox`? I'm open to any methods, but obviously the easier the better.